# Is there a way to know the node give node level in AVL Tree

Tags: c, data-structures

Hello I'm just a new student major in computer science, and rn i am confuse how to set and update node level (depth) when i insert or delete node in AVL Tree. Because when you insert or delete in AVL there is a chance it will rotate to balance itself. Is there a way to set and update AVL Tree node level thanks. and i use c for the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all who view this question. But actually i've figured out how to do it, i dont know if there is a better approach, but if there is please let me know thanks.

Here is my approach, i traverse all the tree and whenever it stops at some node, i give the node the level.

```
void giveLevel(int value)
{
   struct node *ptr;
   int count = 0;

   if (root == NULL)
   {
       return;
   }
   else
   {
       ptr = root;

       while (ptr != NULL)
       {
           count++;

           if (value == ptr->key)
           {
               ptr->level = count;
               printf(">> %d \n", count);
               return;
           }
           if (value < ptr->key)
           {
               ptr = ptr->left;
           }
           else
           {
               ptr = ptr->right;
           }
       }
   }   
}

void inOrder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    inOrder(root->left);
    giveLevel(root->key);
    inOrder(root->right);
}
```

Comment: Nit: your `if` in `giveLevel` is actually redundant. Even if you called `giveLevel` without the guard for `root == NULL` that you have in `inOrder`, it would still just return without dereferencing `root`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Owhh I just realized that, thankyou so much for your help